# How can I create line breaks after <td> and within <table> in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create line breaks after each  instance within a table. How can I go about doing this?

```
<table width="22%" height="18%" align="right" background='../images/table1.png'>
<center>
<tr width = '25%' height = '75px'>

<td>
<p><b><font face='arial'>Title:</font></font> <i>output</i></font></b></p>
</td>

<td>
<p><b><font face='arial'>Title:</font></font> <i>output</i></font></b></p>
</td>

</tr>
</center>
</table>
```

Comment: umm.. insert a line break?

Comment: I apologize for the extra </front> tags and the tr width and height that would not work for what I'm trying to do. That's something I'm working on, but I need to know how to do a line break before I attempt anything else.

Comment: @Blake, yes, a line break. Like the enter button, you know?

Comment: a line break is <br>. Are you talking about a horizontal rule?

Comment: I've tried inserting <br> in between </td> and <td> but that did not work.

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xLeostay/1/).

Comment: Yes, that is what it looks like right now. I would like them to be above and below one another.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Vertical.

Comment: do you want the titles to be on the left and the outputs on the right of it?

Comment: Yep. That's how I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to make structure like following:

```
<table width="22%" height="18%" align="right" background='../images/table1.png'>
<center>
<td>
  <b><font face="arial">Title:</font></b></td> <td><i>output</i>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b><font face="arial">Title:</font> </b></td> <td> <i>output</i>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xLeostay/2/)

**Edit:**

```
<tr>

  <td>
  <b><font face="arial">Title:</font></b></td> <td><i>output</i>
</td>
</tr><p></p>
<tr>
<td>
<b><font face="arial">Title:</font> </b></td> <td> <i>output</i>
</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Is there any way to make the space in between the text shorter vertically?

Comment: @KellinQuinn put p tag in between

Comment: Yes, @ketan beat me to it. Table cells (td) will always be aligned horizontally within a table row (tr). So to get them one below the other they need to be each in its own row.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xLeostay/4/).

I used [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table) table tutorial and just adjusted it to your code. Here's the HTML:

```
<table width="22%" height="18%" align="right" background="../images/table1.png">
  <center>
  <tr>
    <td><p><b><font face='arial'>Title:</font></font></td>
    <td><i>output</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p><b><font face='arial'>Title:</font></font></td>
    <td><i>output</i></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: Is there any way to lessen the vertical space between the text?

Comment: Yeah, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xLeostay/5/). Remove padding and margins from all.

Comment: Don't worry though, you can still add margins.